# How to have repeated command bash code/script equivalent typing Alt n

Tags: bash, shell-script, readline

how to have repeated command in bash code/script to represent the typing Alt n as the number of repetition followed by a key and then hit Enter?

e.g. have line code/script for `(typing Alt 7) f (Enter)`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to write a script that sends a key or sequence of keys to another program using xdotool or similar? Or an interactive script where the user could type that, and then … what? Or do you want your terminal emulator/shell to expand that key sequence to a sequence of keys as input when used interactively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, repeat one character *n* times, you can do:

```
printf -v string X%.0s {1..12}
```

Would store a sequence of 12 `X`s in `$string`.

Or:

```
$ echo "$(printf X%.0s {1..12})"
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Though that implies forking an extra process.

You could also use a helper function like:

```
repeat_string() {
  awk -- 'BEGIN{for (i = 0; i < ARGV[1]; i++) printf "%s", ARGV[2]}' "$@"
}
```

And then:

```
echo "$(repeat_string 12 X)"
```

In `zsh`, you can use its padding operators:

```
$ echo ${(l[12][X])}
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

That's a null expansion `l`eft padded to a length of 12 with `X`s. There's a similar `r`ight padding parameter expansion flag.

For count and character stored in variables:

```
n=12 c=X
echo ${(pl[$n][$c])}
```

`zsh` also has a `repeat` keyword (inspired from `tcsh`'s):

```
$ echo "$(repeat 12 printf %s X)"
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

With `bash`, you could always write a `repeat` function that can repeat simple commands:

```
repeat() {
  local n="$1"
  shift
  while ((n-- > 0)); do
    "$@"
  done
}
```

And then `echo "$(repeat 12 printf %s X)"` like above.

You could emulate a `repeat` keyword to repeat compound commands with an alias:

```
alias repeat='i=0; while test "$((i++))" -lt'
```

And then do `echo "$(repeat 12; do printf %s X; done)"` for instance.